# deployment of windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, setup-deployment

I am new to C#, and I've developed a windows application (c#) that uses a SQL Server database. I want to distribute my application to a client machine, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've searched on Google to try and find a solution, but nothing I wasn't able to find anything.

What's the correct way to package my application for installation on the client machine?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Windows App != ASP .NET APP.

Comment: Maybe he's referring to a Windows Application using C# instead of VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a setup project, giving the end user the option to configure the app at installation time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deploy an WinForms application an easy way to do this is to use ClickOnce deployment. You can offer the ClickOnce deployment app to the client computers and also use it to distribute updates.

The following link explains [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)

Comment: When did WPF enter the equation??

Answer (score 0):

asp.net is for web development. You should probably look into WPF:

http://windowsclient.net/wpf/

Comment: Thanks Shredder . I guess it's a solution for website deployment . I need to deploy a windows application ...